# Is while(*pointer) legal in C?

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop, language-lawyer

I recently came across a lot of code snippets that use:

```
while (*pointer) { 
    ... ++pointer; 
}
```

I checked it with my lecturer whether it is good and "legal" to perform such an action, Because I thought the condition would not stop in case of pointer to integers array.

I could not get a clear answer, I would appreciate any answer if it is correct to use this case and why the condition works because it is not certain that at the end of the array will be 0 / NULL that will stop the condition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "because it is not certain that at the end of the array will be 0 / NULL that will stop the condition." well, it is not a law of nature that there will be a terminating 0. BUT If you decide to use 0-terminated array, then you have to stick to that. Then it is up to YOU to properly terminate your arrays. Same as with using non terminated character arrays with string functions. If you do it wrong, it will fail. Any other mechanism to detect the end of your array will fail in the same way if you provide wrong input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good and legal, yes. This is used a lot.

An example, and you want to use a pointer instead of an index (that has some advantages sometimes).

Counting the number of `*` in a string

```
int counstar(char *s) {
    int n = 0;
    while(*s) if(*s++ == '*') n++;
    return n;
}
```

Usually, (convention) C strings are ending with a `'\0'`, thus you know where it ends, and me mere `if (*s)` suffices.

For integers (and anything but strings), unless it's been specified (eg last number is `0`), you don't know the size of the array, and need a variable to tell the size. However, if you know that the last one is zero, for instance, the algo would be similar to the string one above.

Adding x to n integers

```
void addx(int *a, int x, int n) {
   while (n--) *a++ += x;
}
```

If you know the last item is always `0` (and is not incremented)

```
void addx(int *a, int x) {
   while (*a) *a++ += x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> "*Is `while(*pointer)` legal in C?*"

If `pointer` is ensured to point to a string literal, an array of `char` containing a string or to an array of basic or pointer type with at least one element containing a `0` value, then yes it is correct and legal.

But else (if the array pointed to doesn´t contain at least one element with `0` value), it is not legal as you would access elements beyond the bounds of the array with that condition due to the incrementation of `pointer`. To dereference a pointer, pointing past the end of the array, invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

> "If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary `*` operator that is evaluated."
>
> Source: ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (C11), 6.5.6/8

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what a concret type your pointer points to, but execpt 0 or NULL, '\0' is zero too. So for C-type strings, it also can work.

Answer (score 0):

A frequent use case is when there is a variable length array of pointers (for example a dynamically allocated array of strings) when its size is determined  by the sentinel value equal to NULL.

Here is a very simple example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    while ( *argv ) puts( *argv++ );

    return 0;
}
```

This works because according to the C Standard (5.1.2.2.1 Program startup)

> 2 If they are declared, the parameters to the main function shall obey
>   the following constraints:
>   ...
>
> — **argv[argc] shall be a null pointer**
>   ,,,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can go for it. Please note that `*pointer` is the value at the memory location the `pointer` points to(or hold the address of).